# Dynamic sys.stdout memory location, constantly changing the address

Tags: python, command-line

I am going to use logging.StreamHandler in Blender console. But, sys.stdout is constantly changing in the memory.

In Windows Console:

[image: Windows Console]

In Blender Console:

[image: Blender Console]

Because of that, I cannot use logging.StreamHandler. It just does not work, and I do not know why it happens. As a workaround, I can copy-paste logging.StreamHandler and re-implement in the way that it will write messages directly to sys.stdout, without caching to some member 'stream'. But it is a workaround...